# Status bar not works well

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar

I have problem with my ionic project ,
my status bar not showing correctly. there's some opacity on it that i don't know why always showing, this is
my app.js :

```
StatusBar.styleDefault();
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
StatusBar.backgroundColorByName("red");
ionic.Platform.fullScreen(true, true);
```

red or any color is same , there's opacity on my status bar.
my goal is to make my status bar color is same with my nav bar color

here's the screenshot:
[image: problem]

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your `styles.xml`?

Comment: @hrskrs do you mean config.xml ?

Comment: no i mean `styles.xml` under `res/values` folder

Comment: StatusBar.backgroundColorByName("red"); this makes status bar red what you want to acheive.  Be clear

Comment: <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
try setting this

Comment: @Vinodh yep , as you can see there's transparency on the red , what i want to achieve is the true red , not the transparent red please see the screenshot, <key> setting on what file you mean ?

Comment: @hrskrs i can't find it on my ionic project folder :(

Comment: to be clear this is ionic cordova project , because tagging on stackoverflow automatic make first title to ios , maybe make all of you confusing sorry

Comment: Yeah dude, you have to `tag` and specify your question clearly.

Comment: On iOS you have to `StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false)` to enable color changing. See official docs for  `backgroundColorByName` [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/status-bar/)

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings thank you , problem fixed because of ionic view app has some bug. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fix it,
it just bug on ionic view app,
when i compile and test on my iphone , the problem is gone!
[image]